# compare int with char

Tags: python, while-loop

this is a code snippet from my [program](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0n8xXX4vKAQeWdkN2FJdFZBOGs), where when one enters the values asked for, increases the value of that variable and prints the result by exiting the loop after pressing key `q`. please note that my code takes the argument by importing `argv` from `sys` from the user (that's why my name in the command line).

```
prompt = "# "
come_out = True
one = 0
two = 0
three = 0
four = 0
answer = 0

while (come_out == True):
   print """
   Enter q to exit()
   > Do you like Got?
   > What about LoTR?
   > Okay, Fargo?
   > Alright, last choice: American Gods?  
   """
answer = raw_input(prompt)
if answer == 1:
    one = one + 1
elif answer == 2:
    two = two + 1
elif answer == 3:
    three = three + 1
elif answer == 4:
    four = four + 1
elif answer == ord('q'):
    come_out = False    
else:
    print "Not applicable ~~~ exiting"
    come_out = False
```

when I execute the script by command:

`$ python ex14.py Sambhav-Jain`

it does not give any error but does not work as assumed, as it had to run all the way through the loop until the user explicitly quits by pressing key `q`, but:

```
Hi, Sambhav-Jain. Welcome to your ex14.py script.

Enter q to exit()
> Do you like Got?
> What about LoTR?
> Okay, Fargo?
> Alright, last choice: American Gods?  

# 1
Not applicable ~~~ exiting

GoT Lovers: 0
LoTR Lovers: 0
Fargo Lovers: 0
American God Lovers: 0
```

then I searched online and found a way to explicitly cast the `answer` variable to `int` ie:

```
answer = int(raw_input(prompt))
```

by doing this and executing the same command I used for the previous version, it produces an error:

```
Hi, Sambhav-Jain. Welcome to your ex14.py script.

Enter q to exit()
> Do you like Got?
> What about LoTR?
> Okay, Fargo?
> Alright, last choice: American Gods?  

# 1

Enter q to exit()
> Do you like Got?
> What about LoTR?
> Okay, Fargo?
> Alright, last choice: American Gods?  

# q
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "ex14.py", line 26, in <module>
   answer = int(raw_input(prompt))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'q'
```

PS: Please do not mark this as a duplicate.

Comment: A quick change you can do is to ask for -1 instead of q. That way, all input types are the same.

Comment: Please follow this guidline: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`raw_input()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) returns a string.

So you need to either convert it or compare it with only strings.

If you change your comparisons to:

```
if answer == '1':
    one = one + 1
elif answer == '2':
    two = two + 1
elif answer == '3':
    three = three + 1
elif answer == '4':
    four = four + 1
elif answer == 'q':
    come_out = False
```

it will work as you expect.